# Database Query not working

Tags: android, sql, database

Please can anyone point out my mistake in this:

```
 String j = "SELECT " + colPhNum + "," + "SUM(" +colDur +") FROM " + callTable +" WHERE " + colYear + "=" + y+ " AND " +colMonth +"=" + m + " AND " +colDate + "=" + d + " AND " + colHour + ">" + h + " GROUP BY " + colPhNum;
  Cursor c = db.rawQuery(j,null);
```

Cursor c has 0 entries (while database has proper entries related to this query).

This is the final String j generated:

```
SELECT CallNum,SUM(CallDur) 
FROM MyCalls 
WHERE CallYear=2011 
AND CallMnth=7 
AND CallDate=13 
AND Callhour>3 
GROUP BY CallNum.
```

I tried using query(instead of rawquery) but am unable to do it.

```
    String [] columns=new String[]{colPhNum,colDur};
    String sell = colYear + "=? AND " + colMonth + "=?";
    Cursor c=db.query(callTable, columns, sell, new String[]{y,m}, null, null, null);
```

This also returns 0 rows. Please help.

Comment: There is a dot '.' at the end of the query; was this added in this question only?

Comment: @wonk0 - Yes, this is added in this question only. No dot in the string formed.

Comment: What happens if you paste that query string into SQLite at the command prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's Mycalls table column definition? The Select statment has nothing wrong, I think.. Perhaps some column has a string definition, and you have to put quotes on the values..

Comment: Thank You all, I resolved the problem. There was some slight mistake in adding database entries.